# In the grid layout , what the difference between the followings

Tags: wpf, silverlight

```
Width="auto"
Width ="*"
Width ="100*"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Width="auto"
```

Autosizing: Gives child elements the space they need - in case of a grid column, makes the column as wide as the widest contained element.

```
Width ="*"
Width = "100*"
```

Proportional sizing or "star sizing": Divide the available space proportionally. For example, in order to divide the available into two columns at 20% and 80% of the grid width, you could use `"20*"/"80*"` or `"2*"/"8*"` or even `"*"/"4*"`. `"*"` is equivalent to `"1*"`.

Answer (score 1):

The size can be specified as an absolute amount of logical units, as a percentage value or automatically.

**Fixed** Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)

**Auto** Takes as much space as needed by the contained control

**Star (*)** Takes as much space as available, percentally divided over all star-sized columns. Star-sizes are like percentages, except that the sum of all star columns does not have to be 100%. Remember that star-sizing does not work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.

for more

http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html